# Define int-like type in C

Tags: c, data-structures, typedef

I want to define a new type in C, which should take values from:

1. 0 to 16
2. -8 to +8 (another program)

Also, it should take only 5 bits of memory. (Minimum dimension)

Comment: Look up "C bit fields". You can't typedef something as a bitfield though. But you can typedef a struct that contains one or more bitfields (e.g. two 4-bit fields crammed into a char).

Comment: You can't. C has bit fields, which may or may not work for you, but they are not types.

Comment: @Abbey The minimumj addressable unit is byte.

Comment: @Vlad Thanks for that. I've just modified the question.

Comment: the best you can do is use `signed char` and `unsigned char` and just make sure you use only those values. Bitfields would be needlessly complicated for your task.

Comment: @Abbey try to define a bit field with width of 5 of type signed char.

Comment: Is it 0 to 16 or 0 to 15?

Comment: You cannot do that. You need explicit code to access a bit field, and you need explicit code to check for valid values.

Comment: I'll search something about bit fields. I thought it would be something easy. I'm thinking now to some binary solutions.

Comment: For what purpose? Is your actual aim to pack values into 4-bit fields (5-bit for 0..16)?

Comment: Irrespective of your solution, you've to spend minimum a byte to store things in _C_. Oh and yes, a byte may not be an octet; it could be 16 or 32 bits, or whatever depending on your machine/compiler.

Comment: The purpose is learning to make a custom type. 0-16 on 4bits 0-32 on 5.. it doesn't matter.

Comment: @legends2k Isn't a byte always 8bits?

Comment: No, a byte is the minimum addressable data type in C, a `char`. But how wide it is left to the implementation. _C11 (n1570 draft), §3.6 byte, note 2_: `A byte is composed of a contiguous sequence of bits, the number of which is implementation-defined.`

Comment: @Abbey I'll tell you what. Don't let these gory details bother you and stray away from your learning. Just use a byte (irrespective of its length on your machine) and do the necessary implementation using bit manipulation. Whoever gave you this assignment would probably have given it for the learner to become comfortable with bit-manipulation.

Comment: "learning to make a custom type" (1) In C, a type must occupy a whole number of bytes. A byte is at least 8 bits. (2) In C, there is a fixed set of integer-like types, you cannot make your own.

Comment: @n.m. Although it sounds right to me, I can't seem to find the point where it says a byte should atleast be 8 bits. Can you kindly point me to the section in a C standard? Thanks

Comment: @legends2k "Numerical limits", whatever the section number is this year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original question was changed from 5 bits to 4, but the range 0..16 *does* require 5 bits, as several people commented.

You can't use a storage type smaller than `char`. Your problem with come with arithmetic and bit operations (eg shift), because you will have to mask off bits that are not a part of your type, and this will have to be done with (inline) functions or macros.

However, a bigger problem will come with *signed* 5-bit type. You won't be able to do multiply and other operations without sign-extending to the upper bits. If the result is negative, you'll have to truncate these bits because they are outside the 5-bit field. On the other hand, if you *don't* truncate them you are using 8-bit field and not a 5-bit field.

On top of that, you won't be able to print any signed values or cast them to `char` or `int` without sign-extending them first. So you won't really be working with a 5-bit type after all.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MASK5  0x1F
#define MASKX  0xF0

typedef unsigned char u5;  // unsigned 5-bit type
typedef char s5;           // signed 5-bit type

char extend5 (char num) {
    if (num & MASKX)
        num |= MASKX;
    return num;
}

s5 mul_s5 (s5 arg1, s5 arg2) {
    return (s5)((extend5(arg1) * extend5(arg2)) & MASK5);
}

u5 mul_u5 (u5 arg1, u5 arg2) {
    return (arg1 * arg2) & MASK5;
}

int main(void)
{
    // simple example
    printf ("%2u * %2u = %2u\n", 2, 3, (unsigned)mul_u5((u5)2,  (u5)3));

    // overflow example is truncated
    printf ("%2u * %2u = %2u\n",12,23, (unsigned)mul_u5((u5)12, (u5)23));

    // signed example without extending product
    printf ("%2d * %2d = %2d\n",-2, 3, (int)mul_s5((s5)-2, (s5)3));

    // signed example with sign extension
    printf ("%2d * %2d = %2d\n",-2, 3, (int)extend5(mul_s5((s5)-2, (s5)3)));

    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
 2 *  3 =  6
12 * 23 = 20
-2 *  3 = 26
-2 *  3 = -6
```

Comment: You wrote: typedef unsigned char s5;  // signed 5-bit type. Was it supposed to be signed or unsigned?

Comment: Well, this isn't exactly what I wanted. I just want a type (something like int), but with other range of values. The comments above made me think that it would be too challenging, because it is too complicated, and not very useful. Thanks for answer anyway.

Comment: @Abbey if you read all the comments you would see it can't be done, so this answer can't fulfil your requirements, only point out some difficulties in trying to achieve something near to what you want.